# how to get back to previous page when session time out in php

Tags: php, session

In my program i want when the session is time out after entering the login details again back to the previous page for this i am doing like this

index.php:

```
   $PAGE_TITLE = "Sign In...";
   getTitleSetting('Super');
   divertAdminUser();
   $index_local_url =$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/TicketRoom/public_html/test/users/index.php';
   $redirect_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   if(isset($_POST['seller_password']) && isset($_POST['seller_email']) && $_POST['seller_submit_x'] != '' && $_POST['seller_submit_y'] != ''){

   $password=$_POST['seller_password'];
   $username=check_input($_POST['seller_email']);

   $db=new DbConnect($DB_HOST, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME,$DB_REPORT_ERROR, $DB_PERSISTENT_CONN);
$db->open() or die($db->error());

 if(authenticateUser($password, $username, $db)){

  $seller_id =$_SESSION['SESS_v_seller_id'];

 $select_email_query=mysql_query("select * from ".TK_SELLER_USERS." where id='".$seller_id."'");
 $row_seller_id = mysql_fetch_array($select_email_query);

 $trading_status =      $row_seller_id['status'];
 $_SESSION['SESS_v_usertype'] = $row_seller_id['user'];
 if($redirect_url == $index_local_url)
 {
 if($trading_status == "Active-pending")
 {
   header("location:reset_password.php");
   exit;
 }
 else
 {
   if($row_seller_id['user'] == "Affiliate")
   {
  if($_SESSION['sts_aff'] == "P")
   {
   header("location:dashboard/awaiting_approval.php");
   exit;
   }
 else
  {
   header("location:dashboard/current.php");
   exit;
  }

  }
   else if($row_seller_id['user'] == "Performer")
  {

   header("location:accountsettings/performer_index.php"); 
   exit;
  }
  else if($row_seller_id['user'] == "Venu_owner")
 {
    // header("location:https://example.com/test/users/accountsettings/performer_index.php");

  header("location:accountsettings/performer_index.php"); 
  exit;
  }
  else
  {
   header("location:dashboard.php"); 
   exit;`
   }
  }
 }
 else
 {
  header("location:".$redirect_url);
 }

 }

 else{

    $_SESSION['sess_msg'] = "Authentication failed!";
    $_SESSION['sess_class']='err';
    header ("Location: index.php");         
    exit;
}
```

}

i am trying to get back to previous page but it is not working properly when session time out its come back to login page

```
     here my $redirect_url = some previous page($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

again entering the login details my $redirect_url change to login page url

```
       $redirect_url  = login page($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

so its repeat the same page and i want **only for session time out not for the logout** how can i do it can you explain please.

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Answer (score 0):

When you check the session at if session is not stored then create temp session variable and store the current URL in that.

After user login check if temp session variable is set or not. If set then get the value of that variable and redirect to that page else continue with profile / dashboard page.

Comment: in this program $redirect_url is used as a temp session variable